# My component CakeEmail don't send after submit but also don't give back error

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I try to figuret out how to send a simple email from my website. I have CakePHP version 2.10.19. I read about CakeEmail in documentation and configure controller like they said. My Controller and form looks like this:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $data = $this->data;

    $message = $data['Contact']['name'].'<br><br>'.$data['Contact']['description'].'<br><br>'.$data['Contact']['email'];
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('office@kogni-fit.at' => 'My Site'))
        ->to('szymonjozefowicz1992@gmail.com')
        ->subject($data['Contact']['title'])
        ->message($message);

    $this->Session->setFlash('Nachricht gesendet');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contact/'));
}

<form method="POST" action="" class="contact_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="data[Contact][name]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['name']; ?>" placeholder="Dein Name"/>
        <div class="error error_name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="data[Contact][email]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['email']; ?>" placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse"/>
        <div class="error error_email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="data[Contact][title]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['title']; ?>" placeholder="Betreff"/>
        <div class="error error_title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="data[Contact][description]" placeholder="Deine Nachricht" rows="10"><?php echo $el['Contact']['description']; ?></textarea>
        <div class="error error_description"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary" value="Senden">
</form>
```

I try to look into logs looking for mistakes but there is nothing about it. But also there's no sended email in my gmail.

After your advices I change my code. I edit my controller and now it's look like this

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $data = $this->data;
    ini_set("SMTP","serwer1155486.home.pl");

    ini_set("smtp_port","465");

    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'office@kogni-fit.at');

    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('office@kogni-fit.at' => 'My Site'))
        ->to('szymonjozefowicz1992@gmail.com')
        ->subject($data['Contact']['title'])
        ->template('mail', 'default')
        ->viewVars(array('name' => $data['Contact']['name'], 'description' => $data['Contact']['description']))
        ->send();

    $this->Session->setFlash('Nachricht gesendet');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contact/'));
}
```

But after sumit the is an error:
2020-05-21 19:26:19 Error: [SocketException] Could not send email: unknown
Request URL: /strona/contact
Stack Trace:
0 /lib/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php(52): MailTransport->_mail('szymonjozefowic...', '=?UTF-8?B?V2lhZ...', '\nSzymon J\xC3\xB3...', 'From: My Site <...', NULL)
1 /lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php(1183): MailTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
2 /app/Controller/StronaController.php(649): CakeEmail->send()
3 [internal function]: StronaController->contact()
4 /lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(499): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(StronaController), Array)
5 /lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(193): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
6 /lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(StronaController), Object(CakeRequest))
7 /app/webroot/index.php(117): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
8 {main}
Whats that mean?

Comment: I think you forgot `$Email->send()`?

Comment: Yes. I dont add the $Email->send() and it must be, but after adding it i got this error: call to a member function send() on array. Still dont work.

Comment: Are you sure your SMTP server does not require authentication? You should also put the config into [app/config/email.php](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration) instead of hardcoding it in the controller.

Comment: You have right. It's require authentication and the config shouldn't be in the controller. I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you do not set the message body and you do not send the message.
[message() will return a generated message](https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/source-class-CakeEmail.html#1118-1132). That's why you can't call `message($message)->send()` afterwards.

The typical way to send a mail is to use a template and view vars.

```
    $Email
        ->template('welcome', 'fancy')
        ->viewVars(array('name' => $data['Contact']['name'], 'description' => $data['Contact']['description']));
        ->from(array('office@kogni-fit.at' => 'My Site'))
        ->to('szymonjozefowicz1992@gmail.com')
        ->subject($data['Contact']['title'])
        ->send();
```

Comment: OK. I think I'm closer. Still have some problem. I added the template and viewVars, create my template and take the default layout. I will add this code to my content above. Now I have a strange error.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sending emails. This was very helpfull.

Comment: Probably I overlooked it